# How to call MainActivity method from AlarmManager BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an alarm that fires at a specific time of day everyday. I have tested the firing and it works.

Now, when the alarm fires I want to call `updateTextView()` from `MainActivity`, which changes a `TextView` in `activity_main.xml`.
I have tried many of the solutions here: Either I am not understanding them or they are not working.

MainActivity:

```kotlin
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView dailyTextView;

    //TESTING
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dailyTextView = findViewById(R.id.main_text);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,25);
        startAlarm(calendar);

    }

    public void updateTextView() {
        ...
    }

    private void startAlarm(Calendar calendar) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"ALARM TEST",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DailyUpdateReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1, intent,0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver:

```kotlin
public class DailyUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    //TODO: WORK ON THIS
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ON RECEIVE STARTED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Receiver

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent1.putExtra("type", 4);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent1);

}
```

In you MainActivity `oncreate()`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int TYPE = intent.getIntExtra("type",4);

if(TYPE == 4)
{
     updateTextView();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but there is a red line showing for new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); and startActivity(intent). I have tried changing Intent intent to Intent intentNew and changing the others as well, but having the same problem as before.

Comment: The solution worked!!. For some reason the alarm is getting fired again and again after the set time. I only want it to run once.

Comment: Where are you calling the function `startAlarm()` ?

Comment: Currently I am calling it from onCreate(). I feel like that is the problem. The solution that I am thinking about is just adding in some conditons and stuff. Do you have any recommendations? All I need is the alarm to fire once a day. First time working to alarm manager.

Comment: I would recommend that you use `SharedPreferences` and save current date without time then you can check if it's the same date don't call `startAlarm()` , you might have better ideas but I think this one will work.